# How to get a string after another string in ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

For example, the text is:

```
my name is angie merkel and Im stupid!
```

I'd like to get the `angie merkel` from the string.

How can i do this? My head is going to explode...  i can't trim this string because it's a variable
(text from the user for a ChatBot)

Answer (score 1):

If the string always has the format `my name is  and Im stupid!', you can do the following:

```
NSString *name = [[startingString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"my name is " 
                                                            withString:@""]
                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" and Im stupid!" 
                                            withString:@""];
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do a little more carefully?  It's not clear.

Comment: I read a ".qa"-file.
One line of this file is:
    my name is <name>;[Ah your name is <name> very interesting!]
so i check if the user says "my name is" and i'd like to find out, what the user says after "my name is" and then i save this to a NSMutableDictionary

Comment: So you want everything after "my name is " up until the semicolon?

Comment: yes but not until the semicolon, coz i have the variable "question" which is already until the semicolon. In the user sentence after "my name is"